# Workflow Updating "% Compelte" to 100 for a Task List changes the value to 10,000% automatically

Tags: workflow, tasks

1. In my Tasks List have custom Task Status 'Archive'.
2. When workflow runs, it checks if Task Status is 'Archive' then it Sets the Task Status column value to 100.
3. When I check the updates in the Tasks List I see 10,000 % instead of 100 %

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, percent complete is stored as a value from 0.00 to 1.00 so 100% would be 1.

Change the Value you set in the workflow to 1 and the problem should be resolved.